# Como replicar acciones jQuery en Angular 5

Tags: jquery, angular5, eventos

tengo un formulario en html (**Angular**) y de acuerdo a un evento debo ejecutar una función que recupere el valor de un input y lo imprima en otro, lo hice en *jQuery* sin problemas de esta forma:

```
$('#selector').on('change', function(){
    var valor_obtenido = $('#selector option:selected').val();
    $('#input_tipo_texto').val(valor_obtenido);
});
```

Ahora lo que necesito es en lugar de utilizar jQuery, debo hacer lo mismo pero con **Angular 5**, cómo podría hacer esto?

Aquí tengo el HTML:

```
<label for="selector">Selector:</label>
<select name="selector" id="selector" #selector="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="formulario.selector" class="form-control" required>
    <option *ngFor="let formularios of formulario" value="{{formularios.selector}}">{{formularios.nombre}}</option>
</select>
```

Gracias por la respuesta, saludos!

Answer (score 0):

Ya lo resolvi.

```
onChange(deviceValue) {
  console.log(deviceValue);
  this.formulario.input_tipo_texto= deviceValue;
}
```

Y en el selector:

```
(change)="onChange($event.target.value)"
```